# Create one array from 2 Arrays with keys x & y

Tags: javascript, arrays, functional-programming, ramda.js

I have 2 Arrays `xDates` and `yMentions`

**xDates**

```
[1453766400000, 1453852800000, 1453939200000...
```

**yMentions**

```
[5160, 5240, 7090...
```

Goal is an Array like so:

```
[
    {
       x: 1453766400000,
       y: 5160
    },
    ...
]
```

Trying to use [Ramda Zip](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#zip) thought zipObj would be what I need, but the following produces just 1 object:

`R.zipObj(['x', 'x', 'x'], [1, 2, 3]);` => `{"x": 3}`

Figured perhaps I run R.zipObj on the x then the y arrays, then zip them together then set that as the Array for `mentionsPointsArray` below:

```
const createMentionPoints = (frequencyPoints, termsData) => {
    const yMentions = termsData.mentions;
    const propX = R.prop('x');
    const xPointsFromFrequency = R.map(propX, frequencyPoints);
    console.log('xDates', xPointsFromFrequency)
    console.log('yMentions', yMentions)
    const mentionsPointsArray = []
    return frequencyPoints;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function.

The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this `array`.The provided function is a `callback`.

The elements from the result array are objects, like this: `{"x":item, "y":yMentions[i]}`.

```js
var xDates=[1453766400000, 1453852800000, 1453939200000];
var yMentions=[5160, 5240, 7090];
console.log(xDates.map(function(elem,i){
    return {"x":elem,"y":yMentions[i]}
}));
```

Comment: Thanks! Just figured out the Ramda solution as well. Using Ramda heavily in our app as it makes things so much simpler, will select this and post what I just found out about zipWith as well.

Answer (score 2):

[The ramda solution](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?var%20f%20%3D%20%28x%2C%20y%29%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20...%0A%20%20return%20%7B%20x%3A%20x%2C%20y%3A%20y%20%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0AR.zipWith%28f%2C%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%2C%20%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%2C%20%27c%27%5D%29%3B%0A%2F%2F%3D%3E%20%5Bf%281%2C%20%27a%27%29%2C%20f%282%2C%20%27b%27%29%2C%20f%283%2C%20%27c%27%29%5D) http://ramdajs.com/docs/#zipWith

```
var createPoints = (x, y) => {
  return { x: x, y: y }
};

R.zipWith(createPoints, [1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']);

// returns: [{"x": 1, "y": "a"}, {"x": 2, "y": "b"}, {"x": 3, "y": "c"}]
```

Comment: Nice solution. +1.

Comment: Nice.  It's probably too obscure, but note that `createPoint` can be written as `createPoints = R.unapply(R.zipObj(['x', 'y']))`.

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest point-free version would be:

```
const data1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
const data2 = [1, 2, 3]

R.zipWith(R.objOf, data1, data2)
```

Please have a look at a working REPL [here](http://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20data1%20%3D%20%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%2C%20%27c%27%5D%0Aconst%20data2%20%3D%20%5B1%2C%202%2C%203%5D%0A%0AzipWith%28objOf%2C%20data1%2C%20data2%29)